# How to dynamically instantiate a class in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Can I know how to dynamically instantiate a class in Objective-C?

Comment: Alex's answer is correct, but for the avoidance of all doubt, your question isn't quite right. You do not instantiate a class. You instantiate an *object*. An *object* is an *instance* of a *class*.

Comment: Ya i agree with you.Can u tell me how to instantiate a object of other class/module?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
MyClass *myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
OtherClass *otherClass = [[OtherClass alloc] init];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I also wanted to know how to instantiate a object of other class/module?

Comment: I meant to state that other class is a other project and not the name of the class..Then what is the syntax?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I don't know how to instantiate a project.

Answer (score 12):

On the iPhone, if you want to create an instance of a class given the class name you can use the runtime function objc_lookUpClass.

For example, if I have a base class BaseHandler and want to instantiate an object of the right subclass at runtime (hard coded as MyHandler in this example):

```
#import <objc/objc.h>
[...]
NSString *handlerClassName = @"MyHandler"
id handlerClass = objc_lookUpClass([handlerClassName 
            cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]);
BaseHandler *handler = (BaseHandler *) [[handlerClass alloc] init];
```